# How to Hyperlink to a Business Objects Report in Infoview

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects, infoview

Is there a way to craft a hyperlink that connects to a Crystal Report or Webi within Infoview?

Ideally, unauthenticated users would be challenged with Infoview security and then redirected to the report. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [URL reporting](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/BusinessObjectsXIR2/en/en/BOE_SDK/boesdk_dotNet_doc/doc/boesdk_net_doc/html/Report_Linking13.html).

Comment: Thanks Craig, That's exactly what I ended up doing. Crafting those OpenDoc Url's is very tricky though. To make it simpler, I created a new Webi in 'Interactive Mode' (interactive is a setting in the InfoView preverences). I then used the Webi Hyperlink Wizard to form my OpenDoc Url links, which I cut and pasted where I needed them.

Comment: Nice.  I'll have to remember that feature.

Answer (score 0):

There are two answer of your question based on the environment.

1. If you are using 4.x environment then we have direct option in "link document tab" which is responsible for hyperlink.
2. If you are using 3.x environment then you have to follow the below steps..

2.1 Change the Web Intelligence Preferences 'WEB' to 'Interactive'in Infoview.

2.2 You will able to see the option Link to document once you select the hyperlink.

Thanks,
Sachin